# Validation Bean, Exception Message

Tags: groovy, bean-validation

I'm getting started with bean validation, i have the follwing code to do bean validation :

```
 class Personne {

     void validate(Class<?>... groupes) {

            Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Personne>> violation = validator.validate(this, groupes);
            if (violation.size() > 0) {
                Set<String> violationMessages = new HashSet<String>();

                for (ConstraintViolation<Personne> violations : violation) {
                    violationMessages.add("Valeur '" +
                            violations.getInvalidValue()+
                            "' invalid for '"+
                            violations.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName()+
                            "."+violations.getPropertyPath()
                            + "' : "+
                             violations.getMessage());
                }

                throw new RuntimeException(" class in not valid:  \n" + StringUtils.join(violationMessages, "\n"));
            }
        }
}
```

AND

```
class Eleve extends Personne  
{   
     @NotNull
     String nom 
     @NotNull 
     String prenom 
  } 

class Prof extends Personne  
{   
     @NotNull
     String nom 
     @NotNull 
     String prenom 

  }
```

I want to add  the name class of the bean being validated in error message of exception error like this :

```
 throw new RuntimeException(getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName() + "is not valid:  \n" + StringUtils.join(violationMessages, "\n"));
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to interpolate the root bean class into a constraint violation exception. Via EL only the validated value and the constraint parameters are available. You would need to write your own custom `MessageInterpolator`. See also the chapter around message interpolation in the Hibernate Validator [online docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-message-interpolation).

If you want to put the bean class into a new exception as you seem to imply with your *RuntimeException* example, you can just call `ConstraintViolation.getRootBeanClass()` to get access to the bean class.